# array required, but List<List<Integer>> found

Tags: java, list, matrix, arraylist, diagonal

I am trying to find diagonal difference using Array List, and stuck over here.

> class Result {

```
public static int diagonalDifference(List<List<Integer>> arr,int n) {

 int d1 = 0, d2 = 0; 

 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
             // finding sum of primary diagonal 
        if (i == j) 
            d1 += Integer.parseInt(arr[i][j]); 

        // finding sum of secondary diagonal 
        if (i == n - j - 1) 
            d2 += Integer.parseInt(arr[i][j]); 
        }
}
return (d1 - d2); 

}
```

}

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNmK9.png)

Comment: The error happens because you are not using the arr properly.
The arr var is not an array its a list.
change the following code:
arr[i][j] to arr.get(i).get(j)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the ArrayList using arr[i][j]. 
Either change the List arr to int arr[][]
OR iterate over each List element :

```
for(List<Integer> list : arr){
    for(Integer ab : list){
       ........<DO SOMETHING>
    }
 }
```

OR you could also use :

```
arr.get(i).get(j);
```